# Why does parameterizing a curve with its length yield $|g(T,T)|=1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, parametric

Let $l(t)=\int^t_{t_0}|T|(t')dt'$, where $T$ is a tangent vector to some curve $C(t)$.

Why does setting this function as a parameterization of the curve $C$, hence letting $l(t)=\psi C(t)$, imply $|T|^2=|g(T,T)|=1$? ($g$ here is the metric tensor)I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\psi$?  I think that you want to use $C(l^{-1}(s))$ with $l(t) =s$ instead of $\psi C(t)$.  Then the formula follows via the chain rule.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks, I realized I got confused between parametric equations and reparametrization.